# .NET 4.5 Client fails to connect to Web API Service with SSL 3.0 and RC4 disabled

Tags: .net, ssl, asp.net-web-api

Best practices is now recommending that SSL V3.0 be disabled. It's also recommending that RC4 and all but GRC ciphers be disabled because they're all vulnerable to attack.

However if you setup a Windows Server (and IIS) to disable SSL V3.0 and all but GRC ciphers, all .net clients using HttpClient to connect fail saying no compatible protocol supported.

I have set it to use TLS but still a no go and I can't figure out how to tell it to use a GRC cipher.

Anyone have a work around for how to turn on TLS 1.2 and GRC in .NET 4.5 client so that it will connect to a server configured to best practices (and being pushed hard by PCI?)

(And Microsoft, you need to release a patch for .NET so that this is the default behavior!)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding a security protocol

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

For example:

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.myurl.com");
      var response = client.PostAsync("api/Values", model, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;         
  }
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that only works if RC4 cipher is enabled. If you disable RC4 then it fails on Windows 2008 and Windows 2008 R2. (It works on Windows 2012 R2, unconfirmed one way or another on Windows 2012)

This may be a limitation of Windows 2008 R2 but it's a pretty major one if so....